# How to (generally) identify a temperature sensor?

Tags: sensor, temperature, reverse-engineering

What should be the approach to figuring out what a temperature sensor is, when taking apart an appliance or “reverse engineering”?

This has come up in a couple scenarios for me recently:

- I am installing an alternator controller, with a dedicated 2-lead temperature sensor. (I wanted to try a replacement in case the original was damaged, as it had been crushed somewhat.)
- I am trying to figure out how my “automatic” range hood “works”. (It doesn’t really.)

In the first case the sensor was encased in something and wrapped with heat shrink. In the second case it is a tiny black blob (smaller than a discrete transistor style blob).

Is there a good approach/device/controller that could work through the most common types of thermocouples/RTDs/etc. to figure out what it is? If so, is there a safest order of testing given the sensor, and maybe its polarity, are unknown?

Comment: Start by checking the wiring diagram / schematic.

Comment: Temperature sensors are very different in physical appearance, electrical connections, and purpose. Additionally, a lot of other sensors have a temperature sensor on the side, because they need protection, or their reading must be temperature-compensated.  There is not much commonality among a bi-metal thermostat, a droplet NTC, and the sensor embedded in a modern Intel CPU.

Comment: Read the service manual for the device. If that doesn't tell you what to get, speak with the supplier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many temperature sensors you'll run into with consumer gear are resistive and polarity does not matter. So the (two) leads are the same color (if any) and they measure the same resistance in either direction. They run the gamut from precision thermistors used for body temperature measurement to more-or-less linear bulk silicon  resistive sensors used for high temperatures and base-metal RTDs used for temperature measurement in comfort heating. The more linear resistive sensors have relatively little sensitivity, which a bit of temperature change will illustrate. Some are identical in appearance to SMT resistors.

Image: Wikipedia

[image]

Image Newark Canada:

[image]

Image Digikey: (glass bead)

[image]

Thermocouples are necessary for higher temperatures such as kilns and are very common in industrial equipment such as molding machines and extruders. There will be two wires of different colors (or a special color-coded and polarized connector) and more complex circuitry. The colors may be a clue to the thermocouple type, although there are a number of standards and you may need to be a bit of a student of industrial history to guess the code that applies. They generate a small voltage when a temperature difference exists from one end to the other. An ordinary multimeter on the 199.9mV range will easily pick that up with a bit of heating. A type K thermocouple has an output of around 41\$\mu\$V/°C near room temperature so a 5°C temperature difference from a warm paw will give you a couple counts on the 200mV range. One use in consumer equipment is the "thermocouple" (actually a thermopile) used as a safety in gas valves.

Image: Newark

[image]

Image: Omega

[image]

Precious metal RTDs are common in some industrial equipment and food equipment. Typical standards are 100\$\Omega\$ or 1000\$\Omega\$ at 0°C so they would measure around 8% more at room temperature. There are two standards, DIN (\$\alpha = 0.00385\$) and "American" (\$\alpha = 0.00392\$) for curve but the latter is rarely seen in new equipment. There may be two wires, three wires (common in industrial equipment) or four wires (common in scientific equipment). Usually the element itself has two wires and the extra wires are attached a short distance away.
Image: Phigets

[image]

Image: Digikey (thin film Pt type)

[image]

Image: Axolia (wirewound Pt type)

[image]

Semiconductor sensors are more likely to turn up soldered to a PCB than near something being measured. They're usually marked. They may be two wires or three wires. Maybe more, depending on the package. Common ones for remote use include the ancient and cantankerous LM35 and the digital one-wire Dallas DS18B20 and clones. There are quite a variety of other digital and analog sensors, but most are poorly suited for use off a PCB because of the packaging.

Image: Wikipedia

[image]

Of course, any given sensor may be enclosed in a tube or thermowell and you may not be able to easily tell what the sensing element inside actually looks like.